# Angular FormArray setValidators does not work when setting dynamically

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

I have a `formGroup` which has a `formArray`, which contains of `{key: '', value: ''} formGroups`. I want to make the `value formControl` to be required when the `key formControl` is not empty. I have implemented the following function inside `form.valueChanges`. This does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: result => {
      (this.form.get('i18nDescription') as FormArray).controls.forEach((formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        const formGroupValue = formGroup.value;

        if(formGroupValue.key !== '' && formGroupValue.value === '') {
          formGroup.controls['value'].setValidators(Validators.required);
          formGroup.updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: call update on individual control try this: formGroup.controls['value'].updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });

Comment: Just set custom validator to FormGroup to check both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing formGroup value properties to add validation into value formControl that is not going to work any more, You have to directly access formGroup it self to add conditional validation.

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: result => {
      (this.form.get('i18nDescription') as FormArray).controls.forEach((formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        if(formGroup.get('key').value != null) {
          formGroup.get('value').setValidators(Validators.required);
          formGroup.get('value').updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Update your code to above code

Hope it works for you

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine that should be `formGroup.get(value)`, "value" is a variable, not a fixed string. Futhermore it's a terrible code -not yours, else question code- we need take account when you change the value to remove the validator

Comment: @Eliseo value if not variable, it is form control resided inside form group.

Comment: ::glups:: you're correct Jay :(